Rust proc macro to do compile time checking if two types are equivelant
Hello I'm creating a proc macro that I can use in my declarative macros that checks if 2 types are the same, and if so, it will select the first block, otherwise it should select the second block. However I'm getting this error
error: macro expansion ignores token `{` and any following
  --> src\event_listener\macros.rs:25:13
   |
25 | /             funny_if!{
26 | |                 (),
27 | |                 (),
28 | |                 {
...  |
33 | |                 }
34 | |             }
   | |             ^ caused by the macro expansion here
   | |_____________|
   |
   |
   = note: the usage of `funny_if!` is likely invalid in item context

which means I'm doing some thing wrong, and I'm not sure at all what that is. If anyone could help that'd be great.
struct FunnyIf {
    type_to_match: Type,
    input_type: Type,
    true_block: Block,
    false_block: Block,
}

impl Parse for FunnyIf {
    fn parse(input: ParseStream) -> Result<Self> {
        let type_to_match: Type = input.parse()?;
        input.parse::<Token![,]>()?;
        let input_type: Type = input.parse()?;
        input.parse::<Token![,]>()?;
        let true_block: Block = input.parse()?;
        input.parse::<Token![,]>()?;
        let false_block: Block = input.parse()?;
        Ok(FunnyIf {
            type_to_match,
            input_type,
            true_block,
            false_block,
        })
    }
}

/// Creates a compile time if statement on types
#[proc_macro]
pub fn funny_if(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let FunnyIf {
        type_to_match,
        input_type,
        true_block,
        false_block,
    } = parse_macro_input!(input as FunnyIf);
    let used_block = if type_to_match.to_token_stream().to_string()
        == input_type.to_token_stream().to_string()
    {
        true_block
    } else {
        false_block
    };
    let expanded = quote! {{
        #used_block
    }};
    expanded.into()
}

An example of this macro's usage if it's correctly implemented
macro_rules! example {
    ($typ:ty) => {
        funny_if! {
            (),
            $typ,
            { println!("type was ()"); },
            { println!("type wasn't ()"); }
        }
    }
}
fn main() {
    example!(()); // should print "type was ()"
    example!(u8); // should print "type wasn't ()"
}


Macros are expanded before any types are resolved, "check[ing] if 2 types are the same" is therefore fundamentally impossible in general.

The types don't need to have been resolved, as syn parses the code, I'm just checking the inputs. Crates like paste do something similar, as it allows you to combine inputs of declarative macros.

To know if types are the same you have to resolve types… You can check if a parameter is the default identifier for some type, but you fundamentally cannot check if two types are the same.

Do you think it's possible to do with identifiers instead.

What @cafce25 means is like: consider: type T = i32. T and i32 are the same type, but your macro cannot know that.

Yeah I understood that, but for my use case it doesn't really matter as its just used to automate generating some structs for me.

I figured it out with the help of people on the rust community discord server! The code below is my latest iteration. The problem in my original code was that I was just returning the block, and putting it into the root scope, however that usage is invalid, I solved it by taking each statement from the block, and writing it to a TokenStream which I then returned from the function. I also created 2 other similar macros for types, and expressions if anyone is interested.
struct If<T: Parse> {
    type_to_match: Type,
    input_type: Type,
    true_branch: T,
    false_branch: T,
}

impl<T: Parse> Parse for If<T> {
    fn parse(input: ParseStream) -> Result<Self> {
        let type_to_match: Type = input.parse()?;
        input.parse::<Token![,]>()?;
        let input_type: Type = input.parse()?;
        input.parse::<Token![,]>()?;
        let true_branch: T = input.parse()?;
        input.parse::<Token![,]>()?;
        let false_branch: T = input.parse()?;
        Ok(If {
            type_to_match,
            input_type,
            true_branch,
            false_branch,
        })
    }
}

/// Creates a compile time if statement
/// that takes checks if 2 types are the same
/// and if returns one of the branches
#[proc_macro]
pub fn block_if(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let If {
        type_to_match,
        input_type,
        true_branch,
        false_branch,
    } = parse_macro_input!(input as If<Block>);
    let used_branch = if type_to_match.to_token_stream().to_string()
        == input_type.to_token_stream().to_string()
    {
        true_branch
    } else {
        false_branch
    }
    .stmts;
    let mut strm = TokenStream2::new();
    for stmt in used_branch {
        stmt.to_tokens(&mut strm)
    }
    strm.into()
}

/// Creates a compile time if statement
/// that takes checks if 2 types are the same
/// and if returns one of the branches
#[proc_macro]
pub fn type_if(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let If {
        type_to_match,
        input_type,
        true_branch,
        false_branch,
    } = parse_macro_input!(input as If<Type>);
    let used_branch = if type_to_match.to_token_stream().to_string()
        == input_type.to_token_stream().to_string()
    {
        true_branch
    } else {
        false_branch
    };
    used_branch.into_token_stream().into()
}

/// Creates a compile time if statement
/// that takes checks if 2 types are the same
/// and if returns one of the branches
#[proc_macro]
pub fn expr_if(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let If {
        type_to_match,
        input_type,
        true_branch,
        false_branch,
    } = parse_macro_input!(input as If<syn::Expr>);
    let used_branch = if type_to_match.to_token_stream().to_string()
        == input_type.to_token_stream().to_string()
    {
        true_branch
    } else {
        false_branch
    };
    used_branch.into_token_stream().into()
}


